# django internationalizing a calendar and using single character day name

Tags: python, django

I have two questions, I've recently built a django custom templatetag which displays a calendar when called. Am currently facing two issues which am not sure how to resolve,

- How do I display day names as single character (S, M, T,..etc) I found calendar.day_abbr which returns (SAT, MON..etc)
- My site is being used on several languages and I was wondering how do I get them to display as per viewing language. I tried using LocaleTextCalendar() but without any luck.

  from django import template

  import calendar

  from django.conf import settings

  register = template.Library()

  def calendar_parser(parser, token):
      """
          calendar parser will handle validating the parameters and passing them on to the context
      """
      try:
          tag_name, year, month, entries, as_, resolve_tag = token.split_contents()
      except ValueError:
          raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires six arguments" % token.contents.split()[0]
      return calendar_node(year, month, entries, resolve_tag)

  class calendar_node(template.Node):
      """
      Process a particular node in the template. Fail silently.
      """

  ```
  def __init__(self, year, month, entries, resolve_tag):
      try:
          self.year = template.Variable(year)
          self.month = template.Variable(month)
          self.entries = template.Variable(entries)
          #resolved strings
          self.resolve_tag = resolve_tag
      except ValueError:
          raise template.TemplateSyntaxError

  def render(self, context):
      try:
          # FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK beginning of the week, django setting
          cal = calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(settings.FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK, 'ar')



          # render calendar header
          context['week_header'] = [day for day in calendar.day_name]



          # Get the variables from the context so the method is thread-safe.
          my_entries = self.entries.resolve(context)
          my_year = self.year.resolve(context)
          my_month = self.month.resolve(context)


          month_days = cal.itermonthdays(my_year, my_month)

          lst = [[]]
          week = 0

          # make month lists containing list of days for each week
          # each day tuple will contain list of entries and 'current' indicator
          for day in month_days:
              entries = current = False   # are there entries for this day; current day?
              lst[week].append((day, my_entries, current))
              if len(lst[week]) == 7:
                  lst.append([])
                  week += 1

          # assign variable to context as resolve_tag
          context[self.resolve_tag] = lst

          return ''


      except ValueError:
          return
      except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
          raise template.TemplateSyntaxError
  ```

  ## Register the template tag so it is available to templates

  register.tag("calendar_view", calendar_parser)

Comment: Please **edit** the question to fix the formatting.  It's very hard to read.

Comment: i tried but its not working...

Comment: Help is on the right side of the edit page.  It's very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

[**`calendar.weekheader(n)`**](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekheader)

> Return a header containing abbreviated weekday names. *n* specifies the width in characters for one weekday.

Thus for n=1 will return single character abbreviations.